# Delaying Kendo Validation until Submitting the form

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have marked my controls with the `Required` attribute.
This has caused them to not only error on the `lost focus event` ( which is good ) but the **problem** is it **won't** even let me **continue** entering values in **OTHER** columns and controls of the grid on the form until I first type something for the required control.

Is there a way to delay this required validation to when I submit the form?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the .getKendoValidator(); method to your form which allow you to delay your validation.

You need to set button type ="Submit" 
    Refer the following line of code :-

```
var  form_validator = $("#form_reg").kendoValidator({
    rules: {
       /*..*/
    },
    messages: {
     /*..*/
    }
}).getKendoValidator();
```

Also note that as the Validator is attached to a form element, 
the validation will be executed automatically when the form is submitted, which in this case is when the button is clicked. Therefore, there is no need to manually call the validate method.

Note:-execute some custom logic, like alert to the user, when form is validated you may use
[validate event.](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/validator/events/validate)